# How to write a Unitest case for the apache camel routing in the springboot application

Tags: unit-testing, routes, apache-camel, spring-boot-test

I have been assigned to write unit tests for the Springboot application uses Apache Camel for routing.

Below is a simple routing class.

```
    @Component
    public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder
    {
       @Override
       public void configure() throws Exception {
          super.configure();
          from("direct:encrypt").bean(ProcessData.class, "process(${exchange})").end();
       }    
    }
```

How to write a Unit test for this. The application uses Mockito for writing the testcases for other part of the application.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation about Camel and SpringBoot. There is a [section about Testing](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html#_testing_the_junit_5_way) with JUnit 4 and 5.

Here is an example for Camel 3, SpringBoot 2 and JUnit 5

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest
class MyRouteTest {
    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;
    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producer;
    private MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

    @BeforeEach
    public void doBeforeEveryTest() {
        MockEndpoint.resetMocks(camelContext);
    }

    @Test
    void testWhateverRouteDetail() throws Exception {
        mockEndpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("mock:output", MockEndpoint.class);
        mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(yourExpectedBody);

        producer.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:encrypt", myBodyContent, headerName, headerValue);
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```